# How to do pagination of a table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to implement pagination of table in Laravel. This is the code snippet I am currently using:

Controller:

```
  $todo = collect([
  'clientes' => ['id'=>$id, 'nombre_completo'=>$nombre_completo, 'telefono'=>$telefono, 'email'=>$email,],
  'vencimiento' => ['fin' => $vencimiento, 'inicio' => $alta, 'estado'=>$estado],
  'planes' =>$plan,
  'id'=> $nplan
]);
return view('admin.inscripciones', compact('todo'));
```

View:

```
  <tbody>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < $todo['vencimiento']['inicio']->count(); $i++)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$todo['clientes']['id'][$i]}}</td>
      <td>{{$todo['clientes']['nombre_completo'][$i]}}</td>
      <td>{{$todo['clientes']['telefono'][$i]}}</td>
      <td>{{$todo['planes'][$i]}}</td>
      <td>
          <span class="badge bg-red" >{{$todo['vencimiento']['fin'][$i]}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endfor
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Is this not working? Kindly share the error you are getting with this code.

Comment: If the table works. The theme is when I see a 300 or more items, it is a very large table. I would like to implement this.
[link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: Use the paginate() method to paginate results.